# How can I get some information(eg.Serial Number) from a CER?

Tags: ios, openssl, certificate

I use OC to write code. My company doesn't want to use 'openSSl', because it's too big, and we only want to get the serialNumber from CER, of course we need to use write OC instead of opening this CER.

Comment: So what have you tried and what went wrong?

Comment: Oh I have tried to get serialNumber from a local CER data,and there isn't a fine method in documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my discovery,I found that Apple didn't provide a method to get the serial number from the Cer..And we can only use OpenSSl and other C code method to solve it.Unless you give up getting this,and Front-end will do noting.

Answer (score 1):

Certificate is a defined ASN.1 structure. Find an ASN.1 parser or parse it yourself. ASN.1 specification of X509 certificate can be found [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4).

I have no experience with OC but if you want to try some ASN.1 library I would suggest [asn1c](https://github.com/vlm/asn1c). It will generate c code based on ASN.1 definition.

Comment: Kindness and thanks！We also prefer some small C code to solve this question.Because OC is too sample based 'Secrity.h'.